# Offline Access and refresh token with Resource Owner Password with IdentityServer4 and Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, identityserver4

I need to renew session for logged in user when the current session is timeout when PDA device is offline.

I have questions on offline access and how to use it:

Below is from IdentityServer4

> we also give the client access to the offline_access scope - this
>   allows requesting refresh tokens for long lived API access:

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/5_hybrid_and_api_access.html

Does it mean I can use refresh token to extend session timeout when the device is offline?

Must the PDA be online to renew the session in this case?

**Udpate**

**Offline Authentication**

What is offline Authentication in the conext of Mobile Android Apps and OpenID Connect?

Comment: Yes, you need to be online to renew the token, using the refresh token you'll get a new one.

Comment: why is it called offline access? if it hits the server via internet? Please elaborate?

Comment: It's called offline_access because refresh Token allows a user to remain authenticated essentially forever and you shouldnt have this information "online", I mean, in a SPA web application, for example.

Comment: I know that name is misleading but that is the way it works. You can read more details in this link https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/refresh-token/current , (disclaimer, docs in the context of auth0)

Comment: It's worth noting too that the refresh token is somewhat redundant when using resource owner password since you already have the user's user name and password available. As for the naming of the feature - "unattended_access" may be a better name but it is what it is.

Comment: Please see my udpate at the bottom of the OP regarding Offline Authentication.